# String is Null and unable to parse to a number in Android Studio

Tags: java, android

When I click on the cart in my Android app the app forces close.

This is the line of code:

```
//Calculate Total Price
int total = 0;
for (Order order: cart)
    total += (Integer.parseInt(order.getPrice()))*(Integer.parseInt(order.getQuantity()));
    Locale locale = new Locale("en","US");
    NumberFormat fmt = NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance(locale);
    txtTotalPrice.setText(fmt.format(total));
```

This is the error I keep getting:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{c.momos.monmo/c.momos.monmo.Cart}: java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "Momo Champ (Single)"
```

Also this within the LogCat:

```
Caused by: java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input 
    string: "Momo Champ (Single)"
          at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:608)
          at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:643)
          at c.momos.monmo.Cart.loadListFood(Cart.java:69)
          at c.momos.monmo.Cart.onCreate(Cart.java:57)
          at
```

Comment: Can  you paste the code where you `setPrice ()` and `setQuantity()`?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Formatting Currencies in Foreign Locales in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7828364/formatting-currencies-in-foreign-locales-in-java)

Comment: ive tried all that not working

Comment: The string `"Momo Champ (Single)"` is not a number... find out why it has that value.

Answer (score 0):

One of the attributes "quantity" or "price" of the object "Order" is set with the value "Momo Champ (Single)". Please check when you set values to the two attributes.

Also, to avoid this exception put the code in a Try/catch block.